# Django Read/Upload a CSV

Tags: python, django

I need to upload and read a CSV then save to database. I'm a beginner and below is what I have achieved so far using 'django-adaptors' (http://django-adaptors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) I know its not a lot but I'm just doing this to learn more :)

I'm struggling in the view bit of my code (below). I don't know how to upload then read the file into to CodeCSvModel() function? Could anyone help explain? Many thanks. :)

**views.py**

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from web.forms import codeUploadForm
from web.csvTools import CodeCSvModel


def codeImport(request):
    # If we had a POST then get the request post values.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = codeUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
      # handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])

                ====[HELP HERE]=====

        #form = codeUploadForm(request.POST)

        CodeCSvModel.import_from_file(form['file'])



    else:
         form = codeUploadForm()
         context = {'form':form}
         return render_to_response('import.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**forms.py**

```
class codeUploadForm(forms.Form):

    file = forms.FileField()
    place = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Incentive.objects.all())
```

**csvTool.py**

```
from datetime import datetime
from adaptor.fields import *
from adaptor.model import CsvModel, CsvDbModel, ImproperlyConfigured,\
    CsvException, CsvDataException, TabularLayout, SkipRow,\
    GroupedCsvModel, CsvFieldDataException
from web.models import *



class CodeCSvModel(CsvModel):

    codeid = CharField()
    remotecode = CharField()
    active = BooleanField()
    created = DateField()
    modified = DateField()
    incentiveid = CharField()

    class Meta:
        delimiter = ";"
        dbModel = Code
```

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/)?  What exactly is the problem you're having?  It looks like you were almost there at one point--using `request.FILES` to get the file data.

Comment: yep, I think I am almost there with file = request.FILES['file'] but this seems wrong should it not be form.FILES['file'] as using request bypasses all the form population. or am i missing something.

Comment: ok I think I'm there just my understanding of what is happening is out. this works file = request.FILES['file'] and then CodeCSvModel.import_from_file(file) BUT... what i dont understand is where is it uploaded?

Comment: I think you're confused about the purpose of using the form object in handling the POST request.  I'm not a Django expert so I'm not even sure what the Form object does with file uploads other than to validate the encoding.  The file isn't "uploaded" anywhere in the sense that you probably mean.  The file data is being uploaded by the client to your web server and the request object is just giving you a file-like read-only handle to the file data stream.

Comment: so is this read only file in memory? that sound bad!

Comment: Doesn't sound bad at all to me. The whole point of using the `CsvModel` adapters is that you want to pipe directly from the file upload into your database.  The only problem is that most web servers will place a limit on the maximum file upload size, though this is always adjustable if necessary.  I suggest closing this question since it doesn't really have to do with CSV at all, however.  You should read up more on how file uploads work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django only keeps the uploaded file in memory if it is 2.5MB or smaller, otherwise it writes to a temporary location.

The step you're missing is where you actually write the file from memory/temporary location to disk somewhere, e.g.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['html-file-attribute-name']

        # Write the file to disk
        fout = open("path/to/save/file/to/%s" % uploaded_file.name, 'wb')
        for chunk in uploaded_file.chunks():
            fout.write(chunk)
        fout.close()
```

Chunking is the way to go if the file is very large, because Django will read each chunk of the file into memory before writing to disk.  If you use read() instead, it will read the entire file into memory, so chunks is your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

So this worked, I was almost there:

```
 file = request.FILES['file']
        CodeCSvModel.import_from_file(file)
        return render_to_response('import.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```